# Нет тела запроса при отправке из Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor

При отправке POST запроса через `HttpClient` в `Middleware` на сервере (web api) в `context.Body` ничего нет, хотя при этом в контроллере данные есть (`[FromBody] MyClass request`). Причем это наблюдается только на Blazor Server, в соседнем приложении на Blazor WASM всё отлично, в Web API данные в `context.Body` есть. Даже в Swagger'e для Web API если отправить запрос, то данные в `context.Body` будут.
С чем может быть связано такое поведение?
Оба HttpClient'a сконфигурированы одинаково в двух приложениях.
Запрос из Swagger'a:
[image: swagger request]

Запрос из Blazor Server: [image: blazor request]

Comment: а как вы инъекцию производите сервисов и HttpClient'a ? потому как к примеру у меня вначале был Wasm, а теперь Server и они по разному cконфигурированы (HttpClient).